# Pushforward of locally free sheaf by open immersion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes

Say $X$ is a smooth variety (even just $\mathbb{A}^n$) and $j\colon U\hookrightarrow X$ is an open immersion with $X - U$ of codimension 2 such that $E$ is a locally free sheaf on $U$. Since $X$ is smooth, locally free sheaves on $X$ are necessarily reflexive and the only possible reflexive sheaves that restrict (on $U$) to $E$ are of the form $j_*E$ (since the unit morphism for a reflexive sheaf $F$, i.e. S2 sheaf in this case, $F\to j_*j^*F$ is an isomorphism).

When is $j_*E$ also locally free? For instance, if $E$ is a line bundle, this should always be the case because rank 1 reflexive sheaves are necessarily invertible.

Comment: There is no simple geometric criterion for this. For instance, if $X = \mathbf A^n$ and $U = \mathbf A^n \setminus 0$, then Hartshorne's conjecture on vector bundles on $\mathbf P^{n-1}$ is equivalent to the statement that $j_* E$ is locally free if $\operatorname{rk} E = 2$ and $n \geq 8$. We are nowhere near proving this, as far as I can tell.